# booting linux kernel 5.4.0-39, UUID does not exist. Dropping to a shell

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, mount, fstab

After update kernel to 5.4.0-39 and restart, grub drop to BusyBox with

> ALERT! UUID=8a9ba022-19a3-44ac-9632-d8c8cc1b44a3 does not exist. Dropping to a shell.

I did tried **update-initramfs -u -k 5.4.0-39-generic** It give me some warnings and the problem still occur.

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -u -k 5.4.0-39-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-39-generic
cat: /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_sP1jnK/lib/modules/5.4.0-39-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open modules.order at /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_sP1jnK/lib/modules/5.4.0-39-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open modules.builtin at /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_sP1jnK/lib/modules/5.4.0-39-generic: No such file or directory
```

**cat /etc/fstab**

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=8a9ba022-19a3-44ac-9632-d8c8cc1b44a3 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=BCF4-D95C  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=6b22cca4-e849-4c0a-a327-1874ca06f54a none            swap    sw              0       0
```

**blkid**

```
$ blkid
/dev/sda8: UUID="6b22cca4-e849-4c0a-a327-1874ca06f54a" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="fc730383-fa7d-4ae8-9cdb-75cebd8b69e9"
/dev/sda7: UUID="8a9ba022-19a3-44ac-9632-d8c8cc1b44a3" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="1462f7f1-595b-4afb-97fb-34f0107794a6"
```